# How to combine multiple if statements with multiple outcomes?

Tags: linux, awk

I have this awk code ($1,2,3 are int numbers.)

```
awk '{
    if($1 > $2 && $1 > $3) {print $1} 
    if($1 < $2 $$ $2 > $3) {print $2} 
    if($3 > $1 && $3 > $2) {print $3}}' /var/lab/lab2/awk/preke
```

How can I go about fixing it that if one of the statements is true, it would print out different `$key`?

Comment: Please post sample Input and expected sample output in your post in CODE TAGS.

Comment: and what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Good chance `($1 < $2 $$ $2 > $3)` is supposed to be `($1 < $2 && $2 > $3)`

Comment: Are you just trying to print the max of 3 numbers?  There are better ways to do that.

Comment: sample input `11 15,75 98,58` desired out put `98,58`. And lets say there are like 5 lines of these types numbers, i want to print out the biggest in all lines

Comment: Don't post sample input/output in comments - add it to your question and make sure it's something that when used in a test would prove that the script works (or doesn't). Don't say "lets say..." - show it. See [ask] if that's not clear and, again, read the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: In general, I would, for readability try to keep either the order of variables constant, or the order of operators. `($1 > $2 && $1 > $3),  ($2 > $1 && $2 > $3),  ($3 > $1 && $3 > $2)` (without layout/linebreaks, not that obvious).

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement `max` function

```
$ awk '{max=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if(max<$i) max=$i; print max}' file
```

this will work for any number of fields.

Comment: Best I can tell that wouldn't do what the OP asked for in her comment - `sample input 11 15,75 98,58 desired out put 98,58` but then again idk what that sample input really means. I don't even know if commas are the decimal point in her locale (but then she also said the values are integers) or are separators in a CSV or are intended to represent newlines or something else. Posting answers at this stage is just shooting in the dark...

Comment: years of extrapolating vague user requirements into code :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are trying to find maximum of given three numbers. Try using ternary operator i.e if a>b then return largest of a and c else return largest of b and c.

`awk '{ max=$1>$2 ? ($1>$3?$1:$2) : ($2>$3?$2:$3); print $max; }'`